# How do I delete every row that has a value for a specific column smaller than certain limit?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset and would like to .drop() every column that corresponds to a cell of a "Cell_Area" smaller than 100.

This is the dataset;
[image]

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First select all indexes where your requirement is met, then use the `drop` method to remove them in-place

```py
df.drop(df.loc[df.CellArea < 100].index, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean indexing to select rows

```py
df = df[~(df['Cell_Area'] < 100)]

# Or

df = df[df['Cell_Area'] >= 100]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can work

df.drop(df[df['Cell_Area'] < 100].index, inplace = True)